# Get variables show up in sub-sub directory rewrites, mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

my site link is domain.com/index?page=projects

Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\ /(.*)\.php(\?.*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule .* $0.php


</IfModule>
```

I want to convert get vars as a sub directory.
Like this: domain.com/index/projects or domain.com/projects
How to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rules so that they look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\ /(.*)\.php(?:\?page=([^&\ ]+)|)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: result is: domain.com/index/projects?page=projects.  Is this possible to change like this: domain.com/index/projects ?

Comment: @user3374605 sorry, forgot the `?` at the end of the rule

Comment: like this?: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php? [L]

Comment: @user3374605 no, edited my answer. At the end of the redirect rule `/%1/%2?`

Comment: thanks a lot. this works fine but not work my new link with 2 get var: index.php?page=fullProjects&id=1. can I also add this rules?